# Spark Memory Leak with MatrixFactorizationModel.recommendProductsForUsers(num: Int)

Tags: apache-spark, memory-leaks, matrix-factorization

I am preparing user recommendations based on Collaborative filtering. For this I have used org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation._ .
But I have experienced a job failure due to spark memory leak when I ran the job with around size of 7GB. But I am getting results with small size data set.

ALS model configurations :

- rank  50
- iterations  15
- lamdha  0.25
- alpha  300

Spark Cluster Details :

- nodes  9
- memory 64 GB per node
- cores 4 per node

Running configurations :

```
--num-executors 16 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 32G
```

Code :

```
def generateTopKProductRecommendations(topK : Int = 20: RDD[Row] = {
       model.recommendProductsForUsers(topK)
      .map{ r => Row(r._1, r._2.map(x => x.product).toSeq)}
}
```

Even I tried to debug with,

```
model.recommendProductsForUsers(topK)
      .map{ r => Row(r._1)}
```

YARN log :

```
16/11/08 06:33:48 ERROR executor.Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 67108864 bytes, TID = 8796
16/11/08 06:33:48 ERROR executor.Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 67108864 bytes, TID = 8791
16/11/08 06:33:48 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42340
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42340
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:156)......

16/11/08 06:33:48 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42340
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42340
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:88)
```

---

Comment: What makes you say that it's a memory leak ? Would you care about posting the error log that you are getting ?

Comment: @eliasah :  added YARN error log

Comment: I believe that you enabled checkpoint inside the Spark context ?

Comment: @eliasah:Yes I was

Comment: @eliasah plz find full YARN log https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5oFVIhxzfzPcmJ3TzBvQ25HU0U

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I get a computer access. I can't open it from my mobile.